# how to get the setOnCheckedChangeListener for dynamically added multiple togglebutton in Android

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, togglebutton

I have successfully added dynamic multiple `togglebutton` in `activity`. But I am stuck  handling `setOnCheckedChangeListener` of each `togglebutton`.

i created demo code snippet.

```
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

            el = new LinearLayout(this);
            el.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams emailLinearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            el.setLayoutParams(emailLinearParams);
            el.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams emailTxtParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.9f);

            TextView emailTxt = new TextView(this);
            emailTxt.setText("demo");
            emailTxt.setLayoutParams(emailTxtParams);
            emailTxt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

            el.addView(emailTxt);

            ToggleButton toggleEmailBtn = new ToggleButton(this);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams emailToggleBtnParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.1f);

            toggleEmailBtn.setLayoutParams(emailToggleBtnParams);

            el.addView(toggleEmailBtn);

            linearLayout.addView(el);

        }
```

Comment: Post your code, as it's hard to suggest anything based on the description of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried and solved with good answer :)

```
ToggleButton tglBtn[];
```

In `onCreate()`

```
tglBtn = new ToggleButton[6];

   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

            el = new LinearLayout(this);
            el.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams emailLinearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            el.setLayoutParams(emailLinearParams);
            el.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams emailTxtParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.9f);

            TextView emailTxt = new TextView(this);
            emailTxt.setText("demo");
            emailTxt.setLayoutParams(emailTxtParams);
            emailTxt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

            el.addView(emailTxt);

            tglBtn[i] = new ToggleButton(this);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams emailToggleBtnParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.1f);

            tglBtn[i].setLayoutParams(emailToggleBtnParams);

            el.addView(tglBtn[i]);

            linearLayout.addView(el);

            tglBtn[i]
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(handleOnClick(
                            tglBtn[i], i));

        }
```

use method to handle `onclick` on `togglebuttons`

```
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener handleOnClick(
            final ToggleButton button, final int id) {
        return new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cbtn, boolean isCheck) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "clicked "+id);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: if you solved your problem, then post here your solution for users that will encounter the same problem.

Comment: added my answer, Hope this will helps to other who will going encounter with same problem.